# How to remove category page without removing category in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

The trouble is: there is a category named "Articles" on WP website. Also there is a page like `/category/articles`, it is displayed like usual blog page with right sidebar and so on. I don't need this page, because I have another page to display articles with another template. How can I remove the category page without removing category? (I can't remove category, because posts from it are diplayed in other place on website)

Answer (score 1):

I want to inform you that this link :

```
/category/articles
```

: is not any page although it is come from file : category.php : 
But if you rename this file then all the category posts are not displaying from this file.
Here is the file structure for displaying the category posts.
category.php => archive.php => index.php 
http://uniapple.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/wordpress_structure1.jpg
 If you provide me the own website URL then I can give you an grand suggestion. 
Thanking you.

Comment: Thank you! Am I right that removing such page `/category/articles` is not possible in WP?

Comment: Yes you are right . It is not a page but it is an category posts . For displaying category page, It needs the category.php file in active theme. So if you rename the file : category.php : Location : wp-content/themes/#Your active theme#/category.php then it will not showing the posts.

You can also create an template for showing the category posts.